# Winter 17 Navigation bar does not always highlight selected record

Tags: navigation

On my winter 17 org, on some objects record the new navigation bar is highlighted when opening a record, like contact:

[image: Contact Record]

But on others (custom objects and also standard ones), the navigation bar does not highlight the selected object type.

For example, in the picture below I have selected a product (standard object), but the product in the navigation bar is not highlighted:

[image]

I have tried adding a default record page and deleting it, and also different objects.

This behavior is inconsistent, can anyone help me fixing this?

Thanks

Itai