# Problems with Nav Tabs for multiple Lightning custom Tabs

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, tab, tabpanel

I have a custom lightning tab tab1 added to my app. When I click on the tab1 I could see the nav tab is active for tab1.

[image]

Now I'm trying to add another custom tab tab2 to my app. Now when I click on to the tab1 or tab2, nav tab isn't active to those custom tabs.

[image]

But this works when I try to navigate to the default tabs like home/contact.

[image]

Is this a bug / do we have any solution for this?

I don't have much code in those tab1 and tab2 components..

tab1

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable" >
    hello1
</aura:component>
```

tab2

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable" >
        hello2
    </aura:component>
```

Comment: share your code as well

Comment: @TusharSharma it doesnt have much code in the tab components..

Comment: You can active and inactive dynamically i n controller using aura:id's, ex: adding and removing classes.

Comment: I have the same problem and have added a question [here] (http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/140403/winter-17-navigation-bar-does-not-always-highlight-selected-record), I think this is a bug and I have asked Salesforce to help me on it (for now they are looking at it)

Comment: I think its a bug . Did any of you filed a bug with SFDC ?