# How to make a VisualForce page used as View-override to hilite the current tab in LEX like in Aloha

Tags: visualforce, lightning-experience, tab

I have overridden the view of contact here

[image]

Now in Aloha the Contact-tab will be hilited because I use Contact as Standard Controller:

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" extensions="elfBauCRM_ContactView">
```

It will look as expected like this

[image]

Unfortunately in LEX the same page doesn't hilite the tab

[image]

Why is that so?

How this can be improved?

Comment: I have the same problem with the highlited tab, also [asked](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/140403/winter-17-navigation-bar-does-not-always-highlight-selected-record) a few months ago but had no answer, aslo I have opened a case in Salesforce but had no help from them since the use of app builder it is a development issue and  I do not have this kind of support.