# Visualforce tabs not showing as highlighted in Lightning Experience

Tags: visualforce, lightning-experience, tab

Our managed app has several VisualForce based tabs.  When I switch to Lightning Experience the tabs all display correctly along with the default "Home" tab which is initially shown selected with the slds-is-active styling.  When I click one of our custom VisualForce tabs, it gets selected properly and the style of the tab reflects this with slds-is-active styling.  However, when I click a second custom VisualForce tab the highlighting of the tab no longer works.  It is missing the slds-is-active style.  If I go back to home the highlighting works again.  The tabs and pages are configured as follows...

Overview.tab

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomTab xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <label>Overview</label>
    <mobileReady>false</mobileReady>
    <motif>Custom38: Camera</motif>
    <page>Overview</page>
</CustomTab>
```

Overview.page

```
<apex:page tabStyle="Overview__tab" sidebar="false" applyBodyTag="false">
    This is overview page.
</apex:page>
```

Is there something I need to put on the Visualforce page to get it to stay highlighted?

Watch video:  https://www.screencast.com/t/thzRE7upb

Comment: I have the same problem even with standard object pages if I use the app builder to override the default page layout - see [my question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/140403/winter-17-navigation-bar-does-not-always-highlight-selected-record). I have tried to contact Salesforce on this problem but could not get any results

Comment: Yes, looks like exact same issue.  I spent all day trying different <apex:page> options but nothing works.  I'm also seeing a crossdomain error in the browser console, see new video.

Answer (score 1):

After working with Salesforce customer support (partner case 15485269), this issue which occurred in the Winter '17 release has been resolved in the Spring '17 release.  I have tested on my own org where the issue occurred and verified their fix after it was upgraded to Spring '17.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include a Salesforce support case number, if possible, or a related issue for others to view and verify?  If you aren't able too, that's alright, but having that link can be helpful in case of regressions.

Comment: Sure, the partner support case was 15485269.  I'll add it above as well.  I don't know that I can link directly to it, but if this works for others here it is...

https://partners.salesforce.com/partnerCaseDetails?id=5000M00000gHZKGQA4

Comment: Doesn't look like it, but in case anyone else needs to contact support, being able to provide the number of a previous case can be useful.

Comment: Is custom object tab style work? for example if we give tab style like tabStyle="Custom_Object__c" Will it work?

Answer (score 0):

This is a content settings issue in Chrome.  Go to Chrome -> Preferences -> Show Advanced Settings -> Privacy -> Content Settings -> Cookies -> uncheck Blocks Third-Party Cookies and Site Data

Comment: No this is not the issue.  I have that option unchecked already.