# Visualforce navigation tab not showing as highlighted in Lightning Experience

Tags: visualforce, lightning-experience, navigation

The managed app being created has two VisualForce pages with tabs that work fine.

One tab is a "list page" of custom objects, which can be clicked on for more detail. The click navigates to one three detail pages (all Visualforce). The spec calls for the navigation choice of the "list page" to remain highlighted, even though underneath, we're looking at different page.

From the docs, it looks like I have only to set the tabStyle and call the tab name of the "list page".

From [this post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/154590/visualforce-tabs-not-showing-as-highlighted-in-lightning-experience), it looks like it was a known issue from several release ago that has been fixed.

From [this other post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/174530/visualforce-tab-highlight-in-lightning-experience), I switched to sforce.one navigation calls, but to to no avail.

I've simplified as much as possible into this VFP test page, the Page Reference code call, and the result I'm seeing.

The new test VFP page:

```
<apex:page tabStyle="VS_Integrations__tab"  >
  <h1>Congratulations</h1>
  This is your new Page
</apex:page>
```

Simplified code making the call via a commandLink action:

```
  public PageReference IntegrationDetail(){
     PageReference pageRef;
     pageRef = Page.Test;
     pageRef.setRedirect(true);
     return pageRef;
  }
```

And what I'm seeing:

[image]

Why isn't the VS_Integrations__tab being highlighted as selected?